# Mean and standart deviation by groups where a condition is satisfied

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have such a data frame(df) which is just a sapmle:

```
group  condition values
1      0         12    
1      1         15 
1      1         23 
1      1         14
2      1         34          
2      1         37
2      0         31
2      0         36
2      1         35
```

Namely;

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ),
           condition=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1), 
           values=c(12,15,23,14,34,37,31,36,35))
```

I want to find

- standart deviation and mean of "values"
- for each "group"
- where "condition=1".

How can I do that? Is there any way doing that wihout subsetting? Thanks a lot. I will be very greatful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `data.table` like this:

```
library(data.table)
##
dt <- data.table(df)
##
R>  dt[condition==1,
     .(Mean=mean(value),Sd=sd(value)),
     by=group]
   group     Mean       Sd
1:     1 17.33333 4.932883
2:     2 35.33333 1.527525
```

Comment: posted in same time but I prefer your solution. Would be even better with `setkey(dt, condition)[J(1)][ ,.(Mean=mean(value),Sd=sd(value)),
     by=group]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Colonel Beauvel and nrussell. Both works well.  I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(condition == 1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%  
  summarise(Mean = mean(values), SD = sd(values))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# 
#   group     Mean       SD
# 1     1 17.33333 4.932883
# 2     2 35.33333 1.527525
```

---

Or we could also do it without any external package using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(values ~ group, 
          df[df$condition == 1, ], 
          function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
#   group values.mean values.sd
# 1     1   17.333333  4.932883
# 2     2   35.333333  1.527525
```